# Check What SFTP Client Is Installed

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

On `Jaunty Jackelop` what terminal command can I run to discover what sftp client is installed?

Comment: Do you want to know which client is installed, or which is running? Your question's title and body disagree.

Comment: @user5071535 -- which is installed (question edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the command below

```
dpkg -l | grep sftp
```

[Similar question was answered here](https://askubuntu.com/a/448848/252822)